# describe( ) in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i'm trying to find the equivalent of describe() in CakePHP 3.x

Here is the version 2.x documentation
[DataSource::describe()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/class-DataSource.html#_describe)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this could help you?

http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Database.Schema.Collection.html#_describe

It seems to be the samen functionality...